# How to apply combined filter criteria in a function to conduct a simple frequency analysis

Tags: r, functional-programming, iteration

Here is some data to demonstrate my problem:

```
garden <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) %>% as.numeric
apples <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,NA,NA,1) %>% as.integer ()
cherries <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,NA,NA,1) %>% as.integer ()
pears <- c(0,NA,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0)  %>% as.integer ()
veg_tomatoes <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,NA) %>% as.integer ()
veg_onions <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0) %>% as.integer ()
veg_peas <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) %>%  as.integer ()
veg_beans <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1) %>% as.integer ()

garden <- data.frame(garden,apples,cherries,pears,veg_tomatoes,veg_onions,veg_peas,veg_beans)
```

What I would like to do is the following:
a) Count the number and percentage of gardens with only one plant (e.g. number of gardens with apple trees only, cherry trees only, etc) 
 
b) Count the number and percentage of gardens with either fruit tree and tomatoes 
 
c) Count the number and percentage of gardens with either fruit tree and one or more vegetables other than tomatoes

I am looking for a functional solution to this problem. My idea was to start off with separate `lists` for fruits, vegetables and a list including all fruits and vegetables and work my way from there. However, I struggle when I try to combine the various `filter` criteria in an anonymous function call using `lapply`. For a single column I could write something like `filter (garden, apples == 1, cherries == 0, pears == 0, veg_tomatoes == 0, veg_onions == 0, veg_peas == 0, veg_beans == 0) %>% nrow ()` for absolute numbers. But even for just one column this solution doesn't look nice, not talking about having to repeat this over and over again. Maybe someone of you has a solution of how to approach these kind of tasks and structure the functional arguments to obtain the desired frequency results.

Comment: You need to convert your data into long format so that your dataframe has the following column headings: garden,  type = veg or tree, plant = apples, cherries etc, and finally a boolean to say if the plant is  present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using multiple filter criteria in `lapply` as initially desired. The solution was to call the desired column within each `filter` using `[[x]]` and combining it with another "summary" column containing the desired criterion.

```
library (tidyverse)

fruits <- data.frame(garden,apples,cherries,pears)
vegs <- data.frame(garden,veg_tomatoes,veg_onions,veg_peas,veg_beans)
total <- data.frame(garden,apples,cherries,pears,veg_tomatoes,veg_onions,veg_peas,veg_beans)

fruitlist <- list("apples", "cherries", "pears")


# a) Number of gardens with one sort of plant only
plantlist <- list("apples", "cherries", "pears", "veg_tomatoes","veg_onions","veg_peas","veg_beans")
total$plants <- rowSums(total[,2:8], na.rm = TRUE)

# Select gardens with only one plant
oneplant_freq <- lapply (plantlist, function (x){
  one_plant <- total %>% filter (total[[x]] == 1 & plants == 1) %>% 
    nrow ()
})

names(oneplant_freq) <- plantlist
oneplant_freq
```

```
# b) Either sort of fruit tree & tomatoes 
vegs$other_than_tom <- rowSums(vegs[,3:5], na.rm = FALSE) # new column showing the number of vegetables other than tomatoes

# Join for fruit trees & tomatoes
tom_freq <- lapply (fruitlist, function (x){
  fruits_n_tom <- inner_join(vegs, fruits, by = "garden") %>%
    filter (veg_tomatoes == 1 & other_than_tom == 0 & fruits[[x]] == 1) %>% 
    nrow ()
})

names(tom_freq) <- fruitlist
tom_freq
```

```
# c) Either sort of fruit tree & vegetables other than tomatoes

# Join for fruit trees and other vegetables than tomatoes
other_freq <- lapply (fruitlist, function (x){
  fruits_n_others <- inner_join(vegs, fruits, by = "garden") %>%
    filter (veg_tomatoes == 0 & other_than_tom >=1 & fruits[[x]] == 1) %>% 
    nrow ()
})

names(other_freq) <- fruitlist

other_freq
```

With the absolute numbers now being available from the `lists` calculating percentages is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

These sort of problems can be dealt with by functions where the granularity of the questions allows you end up with multiple queries and hence multiple answers.

However, there always seem to be cases where one ends up having to write multiple mini-queries to get the answer required.

I've included a script based on a tidyverse approach, I' don't guarantee'm not sure if it is the most efficient. But the principles can be applied to each of your questions.

And it had the  benefit of being ideal for transfer to using with ggplot if you want to include graphing the data.

I'm sorry to say that in my experience I have not found a simple way to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

garden <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) %>% as.numeric
apples <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,NA,NA,1) %>% as.integer ()
cherries <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,NA,NA,1) %>% as.integer ()
pears <- c(0,NA,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0)  %>% as.integer ()
veg_tomatoes <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,NA) %>% as.integer ()
veg_onions <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0) %>% as.integer ()
veg_peas <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) %>%  as.integer ()
veg_beans <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1) %>% as.integer ()

garden <- data.frame(garden,apples,cherries,pears,veg_tomatoes,veg_onions,veg_peas,veg_beans)

g <- 
  garden %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = apples:veg_beans, names_to = "plant", values_to = "pres") %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(str_detect(plant, "veg") ~ "veg",
                          TRUE ~ "tree"),
         plant = str_remove(plant, "veg_"))

# Now you can carry out all the analysis you want

# a) Count the number and percentage of gardens with one sort of fruit tree or one sort of vegetable only (no other fruits, no other vegetables)

q_a <- 
  g %>% 
  group_by(garden, type) %>% 
  summarise(sum_type = sum(pres, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = sum_type) %>% 
  mutate(type_nr = sum(tree, veg)) %>% 
  filter(type_nr == 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

q_a

# This gives you the number of gardens which meet your criteria

total_gardens  <- 10

q_a_pc <- paste0(q_a * 100 / total_gardens, "%")

q_a_pc
```

Comment: @ Peter Thanks for proposing a solution to my problem in such a short time!  I will definitely have a look into using long format a little more often in the future. For the time being I would like to stick to wide format using the solution I propose below. I also edited my question because a) was basically supposed to count gardens with only one plant. Sorry, for the misleading wording.